# Handle redundant regex (sub)strings in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of expressions, with possible lot of redundant code.

For example:

```
(number) is larger than (number)
```

or

```
(string) has exactly (integer) characters
```

I have a lot of these types of expressions and I can copy paste the regex for a number `[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+` But in the end it will result in a lot of redundant code. So I was wondering if there is a method (of module) which allows me to do this more efficient in Python?

In the most ideal situation the argument will be processed according to its type. A number will all ready be processed as a float, integer as an integer and so on.

I might be possible (and this is what I think) regex is not the right tool.

Comment: What you mean by *in the end it will result in a lot of redundant code*? what's your expected output?

Comment: I expect to have over 100 different regex(es). So I will have many times for example this string `\d*\.\d+|\d+` because I want to match a float in most of these regexes. So I would be nicer to match them in other way. 

Because if I want to change the regex for a float, I have to search and replace them all.

Answer (score 0):

> So I will have many times for example this string `\d*\.\d+|\d+` because I want to match a float in most of these regexes. So I would be nicer to match them in other way. Because if I want to change the regex for a float, I have to search
>   and replace them all.

You may assign the pattern (for a substring) or (for a complete string even better) a [regular expression object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) to a variable once, e. g. `numprog = re.compile(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+')`, and use this variable many times for matching using its `match()` and `search()` methods, e. g. `result = numprog.match(string)`.